# Zigbee device types

Tags: networking, zigbee

i have this question in my university exams and i would like to have an answer.The question is:

Identify three ZigBee device types.What is the maximum number of devices from the three devices that can exist in a network as supported zigbee addresses of 16 bits?
Also,identify three application profiles.

(Hope my translation is understandable!!)

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Device types: Coordinator, Router and End Device

Theoretical limit is ~65530  (not maximum of 65536, because last few numbers are broadcasts). Practical limit is about few hundreds.

Application profiles: Smart Energy, Home Automation, Health Care, etc.